# Convert this SQL query to AREL (outer joins)

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I'm trying to convert this query to AREL:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT educations.user_id
      FROM educations
      INNER JOIN schools
      ON educations.school_id = schools.id
      WHERE schools.name = "school_name" ) AS x 
ON users.id = x.user_id WHERE x.user_id IS null
```

I was hoping to be able to chain this query like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def find_by_school(school_name)
    ...
  end
end

myUser.find_by_school("school_name").where(...).joins(...)...etc
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is a bit dated, I somehow stumbled upon it...

If I understand your query correctly, you want to get all users from a certain school, who are not being educated...

If so, I'd go the following route - given that your relations are all properly set up:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_educated_by_school_name(school_name)
    Education.pluck(:user_id).joins(:schools).where('schools.name = ?', school_name)
  end
end

User.where('users.id NOT IN (?)', User.find_educated_by_school_name('school_name'))
```

Also keep in mind, that by convention `myUser.find_by_*` would mean "find something on a given **user instance**". Hence, it should make use of the user instance to find something.

Whereas `User.find_by_*` means "find users in general, by a certain criteria".

Hope it's clear what I mean!